# Lang problem about automorphism of polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

**STATEMENT:** Let $A$ be a commutative entire(integral domain) ring and $X$ a variable over $A$. Let $a,b\in A$ and assume that $a$ is a unit in $A$. Show that the map $X\mapsto aX+b$ induces a unique automorphism of $A[X]$ inducing the identity on $A$. What is the inverse map?

**QUESTION:** Not really sure how to show the surjective part of the mapping to finish proof that it is an isomorphic map. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It is not too difficult to guess the inverse map. Since it is a twosided inverse, we get injectivity and surjectivity for free from its existence.

Comment: If I were to guess the inverse map is induced from the map $a'(X-b)$ where $aa'=1$ since $a$ is a unit. Is that correct?

Comment: I apologize for my blatant ignorance at this moment. I'm a little bit sleep deprived, so my train of thought is a little bit decoherent at the moment.